# How do I use the same package branch in all dependencies?

Tags: swift-package-manager

We get an error when resolving our swift package:

`error: packageC is required using two different revision-based requirements (feature1 and development), which is not supported`

Our dependency tree looks like:

```
 Package A
   ├ Package B
   │   └ Package C
   └ Package C
```

In the Package.swift manifest of PackageA we have a dependency to PackageC's branch `feature1`.

In the Package.swift manifest of PackageB we also have a dependency to PackageC. But this time to branch `development`.

## The Question:

Is there a way to have all PackageC's use the specified branch in specified in PackageA's manifest? (Besides manually specifying it in all the dependencies manifests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the problem by setting environment variables that all the manifest reads their required branch names from.

`ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["package_branch"]`